# C++ Smart Pointers in a Vector container

Tags: c++, polymorphism, smart-pointers, stdvector

I wrote the classic Shape Polymorphism code, but a little bit different because I'm using a Vector container and smart pointers.

I am not a C++ expert, and I would like to know the following:

1. Is there any memory leak?
2. If I don't call `shapes.clear()`, is there going to be a memory leak?
3. Is there a better way to use smart pointers and containers?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Shape {
  public:
    virtual float getArea() = 0;
    virtual ~Shape() {}
};

class Rectangle : public Shape {
  public:
    Rectangle(float w, float h) : width(w), height(h) {}

    float getArea() {
      return width * height;
    }
  private:
    float width;
    float height;
};

class Circle : public Shape {
  public:
    Circle(float r) : radius(r) {}

    float getArea() {
      return 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884 * radius * radius;
    }
  private:
    float radius;
};

void printShapeAreas(vector<shared_ptr<Shape>> &shapes) {
  for(int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++) {
    cout << shapes[i]->getArea() << endl;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  vector<shared_ptr<Shape>> shapes;
  //this works, but you told me that is better to use make_shared
  //=============================================================
  //shapes.push_back(shared_ptr<Shape>(new Rectangle(10, 2)));
  //shapes.push_back(shared_ptr<Shape>(new Rectangle(10, 3)));
  //shapes.push_back(shared_ptr<Shape>(new Circle(2)));
  //shapes.push_back(shared_ptr<Shape>(new Circle(3)));
  //better
  //======
  shapes.push_back(std::make_shared<Rectangle>(10, 2));
  shapes.push_back(std::make_shared<Rectangle>(10, 3));
  shapes.push_back(std::make_shared<Circle>(2));
  shapes.push_back(std::make_shared<Circle>(3));
  printShapeAreas(shapes);
  shapes.clear();//If I don't call shapes.clear(), is there going to be a memory leak?
  return 0;
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: OT: why no range-based loop `printShapeAreas()` ]:-)

Comment: I don't know, I was going to use an iterator, but I wanted to keep it simple for this example

Comment: Your edit works, but you don't need to take the `std::make_shared<T>(...)` part in a `std::shared_ptr` constructor again, it is at best ineffective, at worst inefficient since it requires at least 2 pointers to be copied.

Comment: so, what is your solution for this? :)

Comment: @EmmanuelLozoya, `shapes.push_back(std::make_shared<Rectangle>(10, 2));`

Comment: oooh you are right, I didn't see it, sorry, let me change it

Comment: @FatihBAKIR, I edited it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code doesn't contain a memory leak. So your first point is fine.

No, if you don't call `shapes.clear()`, there will not be a memory leak since `std::vector`'s destructor cleans up the container.

I don't know a specific rule about using shared pointers in a container so I'll skip on your third question.

However, I can offer an improvement for creating `std::shared_ptr`s:

When you create a shared pointer using its constructor, ie `shared_ptr<T>(new T());`, the *control block* or the structure that holds bookkeeping information about that resource, is created separately from the object it points to. This might cause cache misses a lot. However, if you create a `shared_ptr` by using `std::make_shared`, the control block is allocated with the object you want, therefore, by keeping them together, you can at least mitigate the cost of cache misses: `std::make_shared<T>();`. For example: `std::make_shared<Circle>(3)` is equivalent to writing `std::shared_ptr<Shape>(new Circle(3))`, but usually better.

Comment: Additionally if your constructor throws then it will be deleted by `make_shared` but not by the constructor of `shared_ptr` as in the latter case the constructor is never called.

Comment: Thank you, now I'm calling std::make_shared instead of the constructor

Comment: @Guvante: If what constructor throws? What won't get deleted? If the constructor for the Shape object throws, the memory will be deallocated as part of the `new` expression, before the exception gets rethrown.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: You are right, the `shared_ptr` is the one that has to fail to cause that chain of events.

Comment: @Guvante either shared_ptr or any other unsequenced operation. For example `foo( std::shared_ptr<Bar>(new Bar), std::shared_ptr<Bar>(new Bar) )` may leak `foo( std::make_shared<Bar>(), std::make_shared<Bar>())` wont.

Answer (score 6):

1) I don't see a memory leak here.  However there is a potential to getting one sooner or later:  **your shape destructor is not virtual**.  This means that shapes are always destroyed using the base destructor, instead of the right destructor.  I.e. if one of your derived shapes would one day allocate memory,  it's destructor that would have to release it wouldn't be called.

2) Nothing will happen:  if you don't do  a `clear()`, shapes will get destroyed anyway when `main()` is left,  causing its contend to get destroyed.

3) Maybe, but this one is already very good.

Comment: *your shape destructor is not virtual* Good catch.

Comment: Thanks! I see that meanwhile OP has corrected the code in the question.

Answer (score 3):

No, there won't be a memory leak, which is (part of) the entire point of smart pointers. When the `vector` falls out of scope, it calls the destructor on all of its elements. In this case, calling the destructor on the `shared_ptr<Shape>` will cause it's internal shared reference count to hit `0` and will thus destroy the `Shape` object.

Answer (score 3):

1. There isn't, not in the code you posted - even without virtual destructor, `std::shared_ptr` destroys the elements properly. (you should add it anyway though - sooner or later someone will hit this issue, as `std::unique_ptr` won't handle this case)
2. There won't be any memory leak, even if you don't call `.clear()` - the destructor of `std::vector` destroys all the elements, and the shared pointers destroys the element owned if they're the only owner.
3. If you don't need shared ownership, you can use `std::unique_ptr` instead, but only if you have a virtual destructor in `Shape`. You should also use `std::make_shared` and `std::make_unique` (C++14) wherever you can to avoid a tricky issue with sequence points and throwing constructors: in essence `f(std::unique_ptr<ConstructorAlwaysThrows>(new ConstructorAlwaysThrows()), std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo()));` will leak memory, or not, depending on how the compiler does sequencing.

Answer (score 1):

1. No.
2. No.
3. Maybe.  Depends on your needs.  What you've done is reasonable for the program you pasted.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any memory leak?

No, you are calling the destructor of `shared_ptr` here.

> If I don't call shapes.clear(), is there going to be a memory leak?

It depends, if your `vector` lives then all of its contents will live, if the `vector` dies then it will kill its contents automatically.

> Is there a better way to use smart pointers and containers?

`make_shared` can be used to avoid problems if the `new` throws an exception by ensuring that the `shared_ptr` calls its destructor to delete the memory. However that would require a conversion from `shared_ptr<Rectangle>` to `shared_ptr<Shape>` which is automatic if annoying (it involves copying the `shared_ptr` and deleting the original).